# Saving a query in a table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to store a table variable as to be accessed by another query within a function. Here is what I have so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION suggest(p_id INTEGER)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        r_id INT,
        i_id INT
    ) AS $$
    DECLARE
        p_record INT[];
    BEGIN
        SELECT ingredient_id INTO p_record FROM shop_ingredients
        WHERE item_id IN 
        (SELECT item_id FROM basket
        WHERE user_id = p_id);
...
```

I am not sure whether the type of `p-record` should be an array of `INTEGER` or a `RECORD`. Within the function I would like to access such list of values, for example:

```
HAVING SUM(ingredient_id = ANY(p_record)) >= (COUNT(*)*0.6)
```

How can I achieve this? I have searched endlessly to understand how to manage this but to no avail.

The problem with creating a table, like so:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p_record
        AS SELECT ingredient_id 
        FROM shop_ingredients
        WHERE item_id IN 
        (SELECT item_id FROM basket
        WHERE user_id = p_id);
```

is that if `p_id` parameter changes, the `p_record` variables does not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following SQL function can help:

```
create or replace function suggest(p_id int)
returns table (i_id int)
language sql
as
$$
 select ingredient_id 
 from shop_ingredient
 where item_id in
  (select item_id from basket
   where user_id = p_id);
$$;
```

Note that the SELECT statement column list must exactly match the `TABLE` clause after `RETURNS` keyword and this function is only SQL so no need of `BEGIN`/`END` block or intermediate record variable.